# How to download complete directory with decode the names of files using php...?

Tags: php, directory, download, base64, encode

How to download complete directory which encoded in base64_encode() with sub-files, sub-folders & all files and folders of sub-folders using php but names of files and folders should decoded in base64_decode()?

Anyone here who can give me answer of this impossible question? Thanks.

(Sorry for bad english)

Comment: Why would a directory and its contents be base64-encoded?

Answer (score 1):

Sample directory:

```
$ tree directory1/
directory1/
├── directory2
│   └── file3.txt
├── file1.txt
└── file2.txt
```

Use `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` and `RecursiveIteratorIterator` to iterate through the directory and its subdirectories to list all files. Choose if you want paths or just filenames. After that base64 encoding is just calling this function for each of them.

```
$rdi = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('directory1', FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS));

$entries = [];
foreach ($rdi as $e) {
  $entries[] = $e->getPathName(); // $e->getFileName()
}

var_dump($entries);

$encodedEntries = [];
foreach($entries as $e) {
  $encodedEntries[] = base64_encode($e);
}

var_dump($encodedEntries);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(20) "directory1/file2.txt"
  [1]=>
  string(31) "directory1/directory2/file3.txt"
  [2]=>
  string(20) "directory1/file1.txt"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(28) "ZGlyZWN0b3J5MS9maWxlMi50eHQ="
  [1]=>
  string(44) "ZGlyZWN0b3J5MS9kaXJlY3RvcnkyL2ZpbGUzLnR4dA=="
  [2]=>
  string(28) "ZGlyZWN0b3J5MS9maWxlMS50eHQ="
}
```

If you also need directories on the list remove `FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS` flag and parse out directory names from additional entries.

Comment: how to download...?

Comment: For example as ZIP like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29873298/5537425 ? Add more details to your question if this is not what are you looking for because it is not clear.